# Doubt in deducing property of modular function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, modular-function

While studying number theory from Apostol's *Modular functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory*, I am having problem in deducing 1 statement.

> Statement is - An entire modular form of weight 0 is a modular function and since it is analytic everywhere including the point i $\infty $ , so it must be constant.

It is easy to deduce that a constant function of weight 0 is modular function and also by definition of entire modular forms it is analytic  everywhere in H including point i$\infty $ . But why it must always be constant?

Does it omits any value?

Can someone please give a hint.

Comment: @reuns I understood your answer  completely too but I can only accept 1 answer as per mathstackexchange rules. I am  sorry.

Comment: I don't think so because you are accepting an answer lacking any proof, I am showing the proof takes 2 more lines (once it is clear to you that the modular curve is a compact Riemann surface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modular form $f$ on $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ that is holomorphic at $i\infty$ is bounded as $\mathrm{Im}(z) \to \infty$. Then it is clear that $f$ is bounded on the fundamental domain, as this is the union of a compact region and a neighborhood of $i\infty$. As $f$ is weight $0$, modularity implies that $f$ is bounded on the entire upper half-plane.

Since you are reading Apostol, you can now rely on the work he expressed in Chapter 2. In particular, a modular form of weight $0$ is what he calls a *modular function*, and Theorem 2.6 in the book is precisely what explains that $f$ is constant.

Comment: @daviddlowryduda how fundamental domain is union of a compact region?

Comment: @daviddlowryduda is it just because the defination of fundamental region is |t|>1 , | t+ t'|<1 , where t' = conjugate of t and because this region is compact. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Cover the modular curve $$\bigcup_{\Im(\tau) > 0} SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\tau \cup SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) i\infty$$
by finitely many charts $\phi_j$ from closed disks (namely $\phi_1(z) = SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\frac{\log z}{2i\pi}$, $\phi_2(z) =SL_2(\Bbb{Z})(  z+i)$ for $|z|\le 1-10^{-3}$)

If $f$ is $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ invariant, analytic on $\Im(\tau) > 0$ and bounded as $\tau \to i\infty$ then it attains its maximum modulus at some point $\phi_j(z_0)$ so that $f\circ \phi_j(z)$ is analytic and its modulus has a local maximum at $z_0$ thus it is constant and by analytic continuation so is $f$.